# dose new running corn job can effect on last running for a php script?

Tags: php, server

I have a php script with time of proccess between `5-15` min.

I want run this script every 5 min with a corn job.

also I luck php script during proccess....for example if script do a proccess corn job can not run that script again (return false)!

Now this is my question:

for example corn job run in `0min and 5th min  10th min   15th min  20th` min...

and my script finish at `8th min` for first corn job runnig.

dose php scrip break if corn job run in 5th min?

yes I luck script during proccess...but I think if corn job run at 5th min, the connection will be reset and script breaks. Am I wrong or not?

Comment: are you trying to stop new processes from starting if one is already running? use a [file lock](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php) maybe?

Comment: if the script properly checks if its already running and exits if it is, then there should be no problem with this approach

Comment: @Dagon You forget the negative case: if the lock is _not_ removed (whyever).

Comment: yes I have a file lock. but I am worry about reset connect or break script if new corn job run

Comment: @arkascha  I think about that too...for time more than 1 hour the lock will be open!

Comment: seems like - run it test it, would be a good idea

Comment: @partiz As explained in my answer below: there is a more elegant solution: use the process ID.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement some sort of locking mechanism.

The first started script creates a lock file in the file system. All scripts first check if such script already exists. If it does, they exit right away. If not they start to process the normal flow.

The only crucial thing here is to make sure that stale lock files do not block the processing flow. So that in case a script does *not* remove the lock file it created when it finishes, that sill other scripts can start processing. This is possible if you use the process ID of scripts as content of the lock file. That way each starting script can check if the process that created the existing lock is still active or not.

This all assumes that you start your scripts as local processes, so via CLI, and *not* as scripts being execute by your local http server. Local scripts (usually) do not have a limitation in execution time.

Comment: he said he does that already in the question "also I luck php script during proccess."

Comment: @Dagon This sounds more like some implicit dependency via some resource required at runtime. That is something different.